# 95 silerado 2500 diesel died and cranks but won't turn over

Tags: troubleshooting, starting, chevrolet

this 95 silverado 2500 diesel was going down the road and died. Now it will only crank but still won't turn over and now the glow plug light won't light up either

Comment: Any other symptoms felt before this happened? Check engine light on (any codes available)?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it isn't getting fuel - maybe a bad injector pump? - maybe bad injectors? - maybe the solenoid that controls the fuel on / off is stuck? - cant be 100% sure of anything but diesels do usually run unless they don't get any fuel.. (or if the compression is so low that it cant make the diesel explode...)

Comment: what i would to is loosen the injector fuel lines and then crank - if its squirting diesel out of every line then you know its getting fuel.

Comment: There's actually a huge Army/Marine/Air Force manual [here](http://www.skylab.org/~zetan/van/9-2815-237-34.pdf) for the 6.2-6.5 liter diesels from 1990 to 1998. There are usually ports on the fuel rail for GM products that let will let you see if fuel pressure is on the line without having to take them off, but I'm not seeing any in this manual. The fuel line diagrams are under page 36 (21-5 h) and page 225 (21-5 u).